# http://192.241.148.177/admin fails to load css and js so cannot login to admin page

Tags: magento-1.9, login, admin-panel

the site works fine, but we cannot login to the admin page.

Steps taken already:
- cleared cache and session directories
- deleted cache and session directories
- (bravely! - ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280049/how-can-i-fix-the-unsecure-base-url-on-my-magento-installation) removed 8 rows from ..core_config_data, namely all keys with path secure/base EXCEPT the root unsecure/base and secure/base keys.

Inspect element shows "Failed to load resource: ...404" http://192.241.148.177/mage/adminhtml/form.js  which of course should be 
http://192.241.148.177/js/mage/adminhtml/form.js

We are not the developers of this page, just the humble hosters moving the site to Digital Ocean.

Thank you in anticipation of your inspired genius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your phpmyadmin from your host
try once this sql command...

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Answer (score 2):

You most likely need to define a FQDN, (Fully Qualified Domain Name) to map your local IP to.  If its a development environment, you can usually do this via a `hosts` file which you can find lots of tutorials online on how to do such for the operating system you are viewing the site with.

Since the domain isn't FQDN then the cookie for the admin session cannot be set causing the login page to simply refresh with no error.

References:

- https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/651-unable-to-login-into-the-magento-backend

Comment: Thanks B00MER, this plus the answer from Teja bhagavan sorted us out - MUCH appreciated